# How to set listener for current location pin on mapview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

This is what I have done so far:

```
_mapview.delegate = self;
_mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
//iOS 8 API change
if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}else{
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
self.mapview.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 1000, 1000);
```

And I get this view:

[image]

How can I have a listener, to capture when user click on the current location pin. I tried, `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` is not working.

**Update**:

I changed it to this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"MKAnnotationView");

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=detailButton;
}
```

But later on I need to get current location address. but the title is not it's address. How can I show current location address in the pin or when user click on the pin I get the address like house number. street name. City name. State:

```
static NSString *defaultPinID = @"pin";
MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
pinAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:view.annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

self.address = view.annotation.title;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coor = [view.annotation coordinate];
_eventGeoLocation2 = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coor.latitude longitude:coor.longitude];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the default details disclosure button provided by MKPinAnnotationView. Here is the code,

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

      MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
      annView.canShowCallout = YES;
      UIButton *detailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
      annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=detailButton;
}
```

Once this is done. You can use the existing delegate method like this,

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
   //Here, the annotation tapped can be accessed using view.annotation

    NSLog(@"%@",view.annotation.title);
    NSLog(@"%@",view.annotation.subtitle);
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Your identifier" sender:view.annotation.title];
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. this is working fine but I have one issue. Please have a look at update

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling out the delegate method for GMSMapView?

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
    didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker;
```